# Search Results Links Not Working

Tags: search, channel

I have a simple search form.  When the results are displayed, it doesn't show the template group / template in the URL.  It shows just the entry URL.  I'm using the {auto_path} variable.  I realize I could go into each channel and change the URL, but is there an easier way?

```
{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo"}

<tr class="{switch}">
    <td width="30%" valign="top"><b><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></b></td>
    <td width="30%" valign="top">{excerpt}</td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top">{entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</td>
</tr>

{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not an easier way, however in the sites I've built I don't usually mess with the channel path settings. Instead I usually use a conditional based on the channel short name to form the search results and link. Keep it all in the template, ya know?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Could you explain a little bit more?